# Dynamic attributes in katharsis resource

Tags: katharsis

Is it possible to use a map to specify attributes in a katharsis model class. Ive tried adding a Map property with annotation @JsonAnyGetter but that just includes the map as an atrtribute rather than specifying the attributes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue concerning this feature: https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-core/issues/267